# Count consecutive row occurrences

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with three columns: `takenOn (datetime - primary key)`, `sleepDay (date)`, and `type (int)`. This table contains my sleep data from when I go to bed to when I get up (at a minute interval).

As an example, if I go to bed on Oct 29th at 11:00pm and get up on Oct 30th at 6:00am, I will have 420 records (7 hours * 60 minutes). `takenOn` will range from `2016-10-29 23:00:00` to `2016-10-30 06:00:00`. `sleepDay` will be `2016-10-30` for all 420 records. `type` is the "quality" of my sleep (1=asleep, 2=restless, 3=awake). I'm trying to get how many *times* I was restless/awake, which can be calculated by counting how many times I see type=2 (or type=3) *consecutively*.

So far, I have to following query, which works for one day only. Is this the correct/"efficient" way of doing this (as this method requires that I have the data without any "gaps" in `takenOn`)? Also, how can I expand it to calculate for all possible `sleepDays`?

```
SELECT
    sleepDay,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TimesRestless,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TimesAwake
FROM
    (SELECT s1.sleepDay, s1.type
    FROM sleep s1
    LEFT JOIN sleep s2
        ON s2.takenOn = ADDTIME(s1.takenOn, '00:01:00')
    WHERE
        (s2.type <> s1.type OR s2.takenOn IS NULL)
        AND s1.sleepDay = '2016-10-30'
    ORDER BY s1.takenOn) a
```

I have created an SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b33b4/3

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own solution is quite alright, given the assumptions you are aware of.

I present here an alternative solution, that will deal well with gaps in the series, and can be used for more than one day at a time.

The downside is that it relies more heavily on non-standard MySql features (inline use of variables):

```
select sleepDay,
       sum(type = 2) TimesRestless,
       sum(type = 3) TimesAwake
from (
     select @lagDay as lagDay, 
            @lagType as lagType,
            @lagDay := sleepDay as sleepDay,
            @lagType := type as type
     from   (select * from sleep order by takenOn) s1,
            (select @lagDay := '', 
                    @lagType := '') init
     ) s2
where   lagDay <> sleepDay  
     or lagType <> type
group by sleepDay
```

To see how it works it can help to select the second `select` statement on its own. The inner-most `select` must have the `order by` clause to make sure the middle query will process the records in that order, which is important for the variable assignments that happen there.

See your updated [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b33b4/10).